# Is there a way to browse groups on the iPhone 4, created in Google contacts in the address book?

Tags: iphone, gmail, contacts

I currently have Gmail contacts synched to my iPhone but I noticed that , I can't find my contacts created in Google contacts in the address book.

Do you know of any hacks or apps that would allow me to browse groups created in Google contacts in the address book?